# HTML/javascript Rock, Paper, Scissors game not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

Some of the javascript code is based on the Build "Rock, Paper, Scissors" course on the JavaScript track of Codecademy.The "scissors" button works, but "rock and "paper" both display the "Error!" message.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors</h1>
    <button onClick='choose("rock")'>Rock</button>
    <button onClick='choose("paper")'>Paper</button>
    <button onClick='choose("scissors")'>Scissors</button><br>
    <button onClick='compare(user, computerChoice)'>Go!</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
var user;
var choose = function(choice) {
    user = choice;
}

var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}   
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Lose!";
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
        else if (choice2 ==="scissors") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Lose!";
        }
    }
    if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Lose!";
        }
        else if (choice2 === "paper") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "ERROR!";
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, looks like you missed a couple of else if...

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan That's the solution here. Put it in an answer :-) Here is the fiddle to go with it: http://jsfiddle.net/5pxK6/

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, looks like you missed a couple of else if...

```
var user;
var choose = function(choice) {
    user = choice;
}

var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if (computerChoice < 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}   
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Tie!";
    }
    else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Lose!";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "paper") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
        else if (choice2 ==="scissors") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Lose!";
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
        if (choice2 === "rock") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Lose!";
        }
        else if (choice2 === "paper") {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You Win!";
        }
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "ERROR!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For choice1, you didn't use "else if" for rock and scissors. Thus, the else condition with the error will always be called if choice1 isn't scissors.

Answer (score 0):

here is my working one, i'm posting it again because i made a few minor changes

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE></TITLE>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<STYLE type=text/CSS>
.s{font-size:60px}
.b{font-size:75px;background-color:##FF4000;height:85px}
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
var p=['Rock','Scissors','Paper',['win','&#10004;'],['lose','&#9760;']]

function g(n){ document.getElementById('g').innerHTML=p[n]; var cp=[0,1,2]
    cp.sort(function(a,b){return Math.random()-0.5});
    r=Math.floor(3*(Math.random()));
    document.getElementById('i').innerHTML=p[cp[r]];r=cp[r];
    if(r===n){w(1); return} 
    else if((r===0 && n===1) || (r===1 && n==2) || (r==2 && n===0)){w(2)}
    else{w(0)}

}
function w(w){
pf=document.getElementById('gam'); pftr=pf.getElementsByTagName('tr');pftd=pf.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(b=0;b<3;b++){pftd[b].innerHTML='&nbsp;'} w===1?pftd[w].innerHTML='tie':pftd[w].innerHTML='win'
}
</SCRIPT>
<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2900.2963" name=GENERATOR></HEAD>
<BODY scroll="auto">
<OBJECT ID="VoiceObj" CLASSID="clsid:96749377-3391-11D2-9EE3-00C04F797396" ></OBJECT>
<TABLE BORDER=0 style="height:200px;width:500px;text-align:center;font-size:50px" id="gam">
 <TR>
  <TD width="33%">  </TD><TD rowspan=2 id="ww">  </TD><TD width="33%" >  </TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
  <TD id="g">  </TD><TD id="i">  </TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE BORDER=1 style="border-collapse:collapse" cellpadding=0 >
<TR>

   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Player
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Computer


    </TR>
 <TR>
 </Table>
<hr style="margin:30px">
<TABLE BORDER=1 style="border-collapse:collapse" cellpadding=0 >

   <TD><input type="button" class="b" value="Paper" onclick="g(2)"></TD>
  <TD><input type="button" class="b" value="Rock" onclick="g(0)"></TD>
  <TD><input type="button" class="b" value="Scissors" onclick="g(1)"></TD>

 </TR>
</TABLE>



</BODY></HTML>
```